# Editable Table - Make Last Row Not editable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am following this link:
[Editable Table Jquery PHP with MYSQLi](http://www.phpzag.com/create-live-editable-table-with-jquery-php-and-mysql/)
and I have it going well for the most part, but I want my last row not editable. It's a row that sums the data above. Is there a quick fix to the code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editable_table').Tabledit({
        deleteButton: false,
        editButton: false,          
        columns: {
          identifier: [0, 'id'],                    
          editable: [[1, 'name'], [2, 'gender'], [3, 'age'], [4, 'designation'], [5, 'address']]
        },
        hideIdentifier: true,
        url: 'live_edit.php'        
    });
});
```

**Update:** Forgot to mention that user can add data to the table, so the last row is not a fixed number. I have found this code

```
Syntax: HTMLCollectionObject = table.rows;
lastRow = mytable.rows.item(mytable.rows.length-1);
```

but I'm not sure where/how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Tabledit only converts `tbody td` into editable fields, everything else is ignored. Ref: [github source](https://github.com/markcell/jquery-tabledit/blob/master/jquery.tabledit.js#L110),

So to prevent a cell from being editable, either set it as a `<th>` or move it into the `<tfoot>`

In your case, the easiest and most semantic solution would be to create a `<tfoot>` to store the totals. Similar to the markup on [MDN’s html reference - tfoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tfoot)

---

NB: Tabledit will still create the row’s controls, even when none of the cells are editable. These buttons won’t function, so you will probably want to:

Either: Remove them using one of Tabledit’s callbacks (`onDraw`, `onAlways`, …)

Or: Simply hide them with something like: `tfoot .tabledit-toolbar { display: none; }`

---

It’s difficult to tell how these changes will effect your **Add buttons**, as there isn’t a standard way of implementing the Add functionality. So YMMV but this will get you on the right path.